# Unknown column 'jdoDetachedState' in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Hi I go through all the stack overflow  question related to this  but no one have solution. I  am using maven + gae 1.9.42 + cloudSql 5.6 + hibernate4.2.0Final . I want to know  why i am getting the **jdoDetachedState** attached in  the  hibernate generated  query.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.claritus.travelaware.dto.AddressDto;
import com.claritus.travelaware.utils.HibernateConnection;

public class AddressImp {
SessionFactory sf = HibernateConnection.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sf.openSession();

 public AddressDto getAddress( int id){
    session.beginTransaction();
     String queryString = "from AddressDto where addressID = :id";
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setInteger("id", id);
        Object queryResult = query.uniqueResult();
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        AddressDto addressDto = new AddressDto();

        addressDto = (AddressDto) queryResult;
    //  logger.info("query result: " + subscribeUserDto.toString());

        return addressDto;
 }

 public static  void main(String args[]){
      new AddressImp().getAddress(1);
 }  

}
```

**HibernateConnection.class**

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
  import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration; 
  import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
   import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;


  public class HibernateConnection {
   Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("HibernateConnection.class");
   public static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
     public static ServiceRegistry sessionRegistry;

 static {
     try{
         Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
         configuration.configure();
         sessionRegistry= new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();  
         sessionFactory =configuration.buildSessionFactory(sessionRegistry); 
     }catch(Exception exception){
         exception.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

**AddressDto**

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import java.util.Date;

 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Address")
public class AddressDto implements Serializable {
@Id
private int addressID;
private int countryID;
private Date createdOn;
private int createdBy;
private int modifiedBy;
private Date modifiedOn;
private byte isDeleted;

public AddressDto() {

}

public int getAddressID() {
    return addressID;
}

public void setAddressID(int addressID) {
    this.addressID = addressID;
}

public int getCountryID() {
    return countryID;
}

public void setCountryID(int countryID) {
    this.countryID = countryID;
}

public Date getCreatedOn() {
    return createdOn;
}

public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
    this.createdOn = createdOn;
}

public int getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(int createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public int getModifiedBy() {
    return modifiedBy;
}

public void setModifiedBy(int modifiedBy) {
    this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
}

public Date getModifiedOn() {
    return modifiedOn;
}

public void setModifiedOn(Date modifiedOn) {
    this.modifiedOn = modifiedOn;
}

public byte getIsDeleted() {
    return isDeleted;
}

public void setIsDeleted(byte isDeleted) {
    this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
}

}
```

Getting the Error  :

```
 Hibernate: select addressdto0_.addressID as addressI1_0_, addressdto0_.countryID as countryI2_0_, addressdto0_.createdBy as createdB3_0_, addressdto0_.createdOn as createdO4_0_, addressdto0_.isDeleted as isDelete5_0_, addressdto0_.jdoDetachedState as jdoDetac6_0_, addressdto0_.modifiedBy as modified7_0_, addressdto0_.modifiedOn as modified8_0_ from Address addressdto0_ where addressdto0_.addressID=?
  Sep 20, 2016 1:06:01 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
  WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
  Sep 20, 2016 1:06:01 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
  ERROR: Unknown column 'addressdto0_.jdoDetachedState' in 'field list'
  Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Comment: Show the code for `AddressDTO`.  If it is defined as detachable then this column is required.  Also see https://db.apache.org/jdo/enhancement.html

Comment: @JimGarrison AddressDTO added in the question.  I defined nothing as detachable in the class.

Comment: @PrabhatYadav, check this link and see if it helps (scroll to the bottom). https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine-stackoverflow/jdoDetachedState%7Csort:relevance/google-appengine-stackoverflow/WBoLOvkEWHg/e_GsxHQ56vEJ

Comment: Thanks @SaiPullabhotla  but as i am using the maven project i do not have option to  remove the  checkbox.  I hope there should be something in the appengine-web.xml  file.